# What is the most Pythonic way to sort a dictionary with string number keys numerically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

Here is my format, `dict`:

```
{
    "server" : {
        "2" : {
            name : "Chris",
            text : "Hello!"
        },
        "1" : {
            name : "David",
            text : "Hey!"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I sort `dict['server']` numerically, although the keys are strings? All ways that I can come up with require multiple names and don't feel very Pythonic at all.

Comment: Why do you need the keys of a dictionary sorted? What have you tried?

Comment: Convert the strings to integers?

Comment: In Python 2.7 dictionaries are unordered. You will have to use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: @MatthewStory: Python 3.7 officially makes dict order retention part of the language spec.

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in sorted(di['server'].items())}` with that either going to an OrderedDict or a Python 3.6+ dict

Answer (score 3):

Using `collections.OrderedDict`

**Ex:**

```
import collections
d = {
    "server" : {
        "2" : {
            "name" : "Chris",
            "text" : "Hello!"
        },
        "1" : {
            "name" : "David",
            "text" : "Hey!"
        }
    }
}

print collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d["server"].items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])))
```

**output:**

```
OrderedDict([('1', {'text': 'Hey!', 'name': 'David'}), ('2', {'text': 'Hello!', 'name': 'Chris'})])
```

Comment: Can you explain to my why `for key, value in OrderedDict(sorted(d['server'].items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))):`  throws `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` in this example?

Comment: You are missing `.items()` Ex: `for key, value in collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d['server'].items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))).items(): `